# How to use hook_init in a custom module?

Tags: hooks

I am trying to use a `hook_init` within my custom module to add a js file. The problem is I do not see where the script is being called or executed on the front-page.

```
/* Implements hook_init. */ 
function hook_init() { 
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('modules', 'myInfo') . '/myScript.js'); 
  } 
}

name = My Info 
description = My Info Evaluation. 
core = 7.x 
version = 7.x-0.1-dev
```

I even tried to remove the `hook_init` and referenced the JS within the module info, but no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you find what your problem was?

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions:

- Is the module enabled? Silly question, but I've forgotten to do that before.
- `hook_init` implementations won't get called until you clear the cache. Did you clear the cache?
- I will sometimes put a `drupal_set_message('this line');` in various parts of the code to see if that's getting called. In situations where a `drupal_set_message` isn't helping, I sometimes will put a `asdf()` so I can get a "fatal error, call to undefined function" message. Then it's really clear whether or not the code is getting called.
- If the hook_init is not being called and the module is enabled and cache was cleared, then it's probably mis-spelled. The function should be named based on the name of your module: If your module is mymodule.module then the function name is `mymodule_init()`.
- It's possible that the path you are using isn't quite right. Does the file really exist there? I would try: `drupal_set_message(drupal_get_path('modules', 'myInfo') . '/myScript.js');` so you can see the path and confirm that it's right.
- There's some good documentation on [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) though perhaps you've already read that page.

Good luck!

Comment: The first thing I did was clear the cache and made sure it was enabled, so those are not the issue.  So I will try the others, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In your module, did you replace 'hook' with your module name?

Assuming you have `myinfo.info` and `myinfo.module`, the function should be `myinfo_init()` in order to be called when your module is active.

Comment: This is probably the right answer! I overlooked that in my list of things.